# prevent users from getting partials

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-routing

Angular Route:

```
angular.module('AMS', []).
  config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
          when('/dashboard', { templateUrl: '/Dashboard', controller: dashboardController }).
          when('/settings', { templateUrl: '/Settings', controller: settingsController }).
          otherwise({ redirectTo: '/dashboard' });
  }]);
```

Sample:

```
/* client side route */
http://localhost:4117/#/dashboard
```

points to

```
/* controller that returns the partial */
http://localhost:4117/Dashboard
```

Everything works as expected, but if I put that same url in the browser (without the leading `/#/`), the partial will still get returned, which is not good.

How do I prevent that from happening?

Comment: Ghetto rig way: don't have index actions that return views, but that feels wrong, even if it works. Also, it only prevents accidental views, since anyone can just go to the route configuration and see the ASP.NET MVC routes anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you can use as custom ActionMethodSelectorAttribute for your server-side method. For example:

```
public class AjaxRequestAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext,
                                           MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        return controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest();
    }
}
```

And use:

```
[AjaxRequest]
public JsonResult GetTemplates()
{
...
}
```